# Как сравнить домены почт?

Tags: java, массивы, java-stream

Мне нужно сравнить домены почт и получить пользователей, которые имеют домен `@gmail.com`.
Как мне это реализовать?

```java
void task2() throws IOException{
    
    // Второе задание
    // Вывести всех пользователей, которые используют только почту @gmail.com
    System.out.println("2");
    runParser()
        .filter(s -> s.getEmails().toString().contains("@gmail.com"))
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getID()));
}
```

json

```json
{
    "id": 6958064,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "name": {
        "first": "Chadrick",
        "middle": "Bailey",
        "last": "Beatty"
    },
    "monthlySalary": "873.00",
    "birthday": "1984-10-17T01:43:46.668Z",
    "username": "Chadrick-Beatty",
    "password": "a3shYp4RtKOczzS",
    "emails": [
        "Dejah62@gmail.com",
        "Lorna_Lowe17@example.com"
    ],
    "phoneNumber": "684.592.9283 x13888",
    "location": {
        "street": "84436 Brooke Avenue",
        "city": "New Earlineworth",
        "state": "Florida",
        "country": "Turkmenistan",
        "zip": "98029-5397",
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": -39.0855,
            "longitude": -36.2158
        }
    },
    "website": "https://delicious-ant.org/",
    "domain": "somber-dimension.net",
    "job": {
        "title": "Product Research Agent",
        "descriptor": "Product",
        "area": "Research",
        "type": "Executive",
        "company": "Hintz, Rutherford and Kerluke"
    },
    "creditCard": {
        "number": "4477-2259-3629-9212",
        "cvv": "999",
        "issuer": "diners_club"
    },
    "uuid": "4e3596dd-d6f5-4509-ae95-86d7c13b54c5",
    "objectId": "654f75dde4b0b49c824555d0"
}
```

`Data.java`:

```java
@Data
public class Data {
    private long id;
    private Status status;
    private Name name;
    private BigDecimal monthlySalary;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String[] emails;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Location location;
    private String website;
    private String domain;
    private Job job;
    private CreditCard creditCard;
    private UUID uuid;
    private String objectId;
}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно затруднения?

Comment: Как проверить домен почты? Как достать из массива почты?

Comment: Дробите задачу на части. 1 - как достать значения из json-а. 2 - как разделить строчку на часть с доменом, и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

К *массиву строк* не имеет смысла применять метод `toString()`, в результате будет получена строка вида `[Ljava.lang.String;@{hashCode}`.

Если нужно использовать Stream API, то проще получить поток строк из массива при помощи `Arrays.stream` или `Stream.of`, для которого вызвать требуемый терминальный метод, возвращающий булево значение:

- [`Stream::allMatch`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) -- условие-предикат выполняется для **всех** элементов потока, для пустого потока возвращается `true`
- [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) -- условие-предикат выполняется для **хотя бы одного** элемента потока, для пустого потока возвращается `false`

В качестве функции-предиката для проверки домена можно использовать `String::matches` с соответствующим регулярным выражением, но в данном случае достаточно будет `String::endsWith`.

```java
void task2() throws IOException {
    // Второе задание
    // Вывести всех пользователей, которые используют только почту @gmail.com
    System.out.println("2");
    runParser()  // Stream<Data>
        .filter(s -> Stream.of(s.getEmails()) // поток емайлов Stream<String>
            .map(String::toLowerCase) // в нижнем регистре
            .allMatch(em -> em.endsWith("@gmail.com")) // домен gmail.com у всех
        ) 
        .map(Data::getId) // Stream<Long> поток идентификаторов
        .forEach(System.out::println); // вывести на печать
}
```

---

Если требуется дополнительно проверить, что должен быть хотя бы один емайл, следует сравнить массив c `null` и проверить его длину:

```java
    runParser()  // Stream<Data>
        .filter(s -> Objects.nonNull(s.getEmail()) // не-null массив
            && s.getEmails().length > 0 // непустой массив 
            && Stream.of(s.getEmails()) // поток емайлов
                .map(String::toLowerCase) // в нижнем регистре
                .allMatch(em -> em.endsWith("@gmail.com")) // домен gmail.com у всех
        )
        // ... и т.д. как показано выше
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться обычным регулярным выражением:

```
void task2() {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\S+@gmail\\.com");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); // str - текст
   while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
   }
}
```

Comment: Нужно через stream api

Comment: Ваш поток (stream) возвращает строку? Например: "id": 6958064, и т.д.

Comment: @Atamiq, ваш код просто проверяет вхождение подстроки в некую строку.